# This script always says that i made an invalid choice. If statement might be ignored

Tags: python, if-statement

I have been trying to make this calculator work but it always says that my choice is invalid. I tried valid numbers and for some reason it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. I'm still new to python and to programming in general. Thanks.

```
#Calculator
print("1.Addition")
print("2.Substraction")
print("3.Multiplication")
print("4.Divison")
#Choose the calculation
Choice=int(input("Enter your choice (1/2/3/4): "))
#Inserting the numbers
Num1=float(input("Insert your first number: "))
Num2=float(input("Insert your second number: "))

if Choice == '1':
    ans= Num1 + Num2
    print("Your answer is: ",ans)

elif Choice == '2':
    ans= Num1 - Num2
    print("Your answer is: ",ans)

elif Choice == '3':
    ans= Num1*Num2
    print("Your answer is: ",ans)

elif Choice == '4':
    ans= Num1/Num2
    print("Your answer is: ",ans)

else:
    print("Invalid choice. ")
```

Comment: You’re comparing integers to strings.

Comment: also remember that its a proper python convention to use camelCase when declaring variables

Comment: @ironkey _also remember that its a proper python convention to use camelCase when declaring variables_ Don't you mean the opposite?

Comment: when assigning a variable*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: Hmm, actually the issue is the exact opposite. That's rare!

Comment: I wasnt saying his issue was not using camelCase just pointing him to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is your checking if the answer is equivalent to a STRING not an integer!

```
#Calculator
print("1.Addition")
print("2.Substraction")
print("3.Multiplication")
print("4.Divison")
#Choose the calculation
choice=int(input("Enter your choice (1/2/3/4): "))
#Inserting the numbers1
Num1=int(input("Insert your first number: "))
Num2=int(input("Insert your second number: "))

if choice == 1:
    ans= Num1 + Num2
    print("Your answer is: ",ans)
elif choice == 2:
    ans= Num1 - Num2
    print("Your answer is: ",ans)
elif choice == 3:
    ans= Num1*Num2
    print("Your answer is: ",ans)
elif choice == 4:
    ans= Num1/Num2
    print("Your answer is: ",ans)
else:
    print("Invalid choice. ")
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 2):

Modify the if conditions, replacing the strings with the numbers themselves:

```
if Choice == 1:
    ans= Num1 + Num2
    print("Your answer is: ",ans)

elif Choice == 2:
    ans= Num1 - Num2
    print("Your answer is: ",ans)

elif Choice == 3:
    ans= Num1*Num2
    print("Your answer is: ",ans)

elif Choice == 4:
    ans= Num1/Num2
    print("Your answer is: ",ans)

else:
    print(f"Invalid choice.")
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

```
Choice=int(input("Enter your choice (1/2/3/4): "))
```

`Choice` is an `int`.

```
if Choice == '1':
```

You are comparing it against a String(`'1'`). So your if-statements will not work.

Try this:

```
if Choice == 1:
```